# Angular routes doesn't work after url suffix

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I have a application running at www.xyz.com/platform/

and here is my routing config in angular:

```
var app = angular.module('coreApp',['ngRoute']);
    app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/platform/dashboard',{
            templateUrl: '/partials/dashboard.html'
        }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/platform/dashboard'});
    }]);
```

I expect that as soon as the application is opened the URL should change to www.xyz.com/platform/#dashboard and the template be loaded. But template never gets loaded. Neither I get any error in console.

This works however, if I try to run this at xyz.com without the trailing /platform.

Comment: the url is obviously not right. # should start before platform like this .com/#/platform/dashboard

Comment: nope. I need this prefix and it is sent by server. So after login the user is redirected to /platform page and there I need to start my angularjs application.